# Java - How to get each word from ArrayList of sentences

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, string-comparison

An example, how to check if words from list`containsThese` present in list`sentences` and how many?

`List<String> sentences = Arrays.asList("wish you a good day", "warm day", "sounds good");`

`List<String> containsThese = Arrays.asList("cool", "day", "good");`

What I was doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentences.size(); i++){

   String words = sentences.get(i);

   // so here I have each sentence separately
   // but how to iterate through it and add each word to another ArrayList or something?
   // so later can compare to it to 'containsThese' ?

}
```

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Well, two thoughts.  `String#contains` and a `Map` of some kind would be some places to start

Answer (score 0):

With the function below you are splitting a sentence at every whitespace and add the words to a new List.

```
private List<String> sentenceToList(String sentence) {
  return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sentence.split("\\s+")));
}
```

With this function you get a Map, which has the sentence as a key and a list with all the words it contains from containsThese.

```
private Map<String, List<String>> checkSentences() {
    Map<String, List<String>> containsMap = new HashMap<>();
    sentences.forEach(sentence -> {
        containsMap.put(sentence, sentenceToList(sentence).stream().distinct().filter(word -> containsThese.contains(word)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    });
    return containsMap;
}
```

Returns -> `{warm day=[day], sounds good=[good], wish you a good day=[good, day]}`

Comment: So, you've answered about a 1/3 of the question ... but I'm wondering why you'd even both with a `List` in this case, instead of just using the returned array from `split`

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, start by building a `Set` of all words in the sentences, then count the words that can be found in the set.

```
List<String> sentences = Arrays.asList("wish you a good day", "warm day", "sounds good");
List<String> containsThese = Arrays.asList("cool", "day", "good");

Set<String> words = sentences.stream()
        .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
long wordsFound = containsThese.stream()
        .filter(words::contains)
        .count();

System.out.printf("Sentences contains %d of %d words%n", wordsFound, containsThese.size());
```

*Output*

```
Sentences contains 2 of 3 words
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> sentences = ArrayList<String>("wish you a good day", "warm day", "sounds good");
Iterator itr=sentences.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
String s=itr.next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your first answer on StackOverflow! However, we ask that when you answer a question you describe what you did to solve the problem so the questioner can better understand your solution.